# Subring and field question in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The set $R= [0],[2],[4],[6],[8]$ is a sub-ring of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ prove that $R$ has unity and that $R$ is a field.

I find this a bit odd but I believe $[6]$ is the unity as opposed to the conventional $[1]$. I am also fairly lost on proving that this is a field. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You can either prove that it satisfies the field axioms, or prove that it's isomorphic to some field that you know. Do you know the field axioms? Do you know a field with exactly $5$ elements?

Comment: I know the axioms but i don't know any fields really we did one example in class but i don't believe it had 5 elements

Comment: OK, so, if you know all the axioms, what problem exactly are you having in checking them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

$$2\cdot 6=1\color{red}2\;,\;\;4\cdot 6=2\color{red} 4\,,\ldots etc.$$

It has the right ammount of elements to a field ($\,5=\,$ a prime) , so you only have to check whether there are non-trivial zero divisors...and this is almost trivial to show.

Comment: You may be assuming a few facts that OP isn't familiar with.

Comment: That's true, yet the long, windy road of checking *all* the fields axioms is something that the OP, I suppose, may have thought of already...

Comment: i was fairly certain that the unity was 6 as in my post, i am familiar with isomorphic in groups it shouldn't be that much harder in a  ring? but how do i show that multiplication is preserved correctly?

Comment: You're right about $\,6\,$, and about the rest: distributivity, associativity and stuff is inherited from the dad ring $\,\Bbb Z_{10}\,$ , so you only have to check some little things. For example, what's the multiplicative inverse of $\,8\,$ here? Well, $$8\cdot 2=16\Longrightarrow 2=8^{-1}\,$$ in this ring, and etc.

Comment: ah since we only have 5 elements its not that hard to find there inverses haha

Comment: Indeed so, @Faust7.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of a field is a commutative ring with inverses for all the nonzero elements. So you've got a few steps:

- Show this is a ring. You seem to be allowed to assume this, from the problem description.
- Show that it is commutative. You don't even really need to do this--this is integer multiplication and so automatically commutative.
- Identity: Eliminating cases is crude but should work (i.e. [2] * [6] = [12] = [2], so [6] is an identity for [2]).
- Inverses: Once you show [6] is an identity, you can take the same approach here for showing inverses, i.e. [4] * [4] = [6] so [4] has itself for an inverse.

Answer (score 1):

You could try showing that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5$ which is a field since 5 is prime.